# Multi-class classification in sparse dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multiclass-classification

I have a dataset of factory workstations.

There are two types of error in same particular time.

1. User selects error and time interval (dependent variable-y)
2. Machines produces errors during production (independent variables-x)

User selected error types are 8 unique in total so I tried to predict those errors using machine-produced errors(total 188 types) and some other numerical features such as avg. machine speed, machine volume, etc.

Each row represents user-selected error in particular time;

For example in first line user selects time interval as:

2018-01-03 12:02:00 - 2018-01-03 12:05:37

and m_er_1(machine error 1) also occured in same time interval 12 times.

m_er_1_dur(machine error 1 duration) is total duration of machine error in seconds

So I matched those two tables and looks like below;

```
user_error   m_er_1  m_er_2  m_er_3  ...  m_er_188  avg_m_speed .. m_er_1_dur
  A            12     0        0            0          150            217
  B            0      0        2            0          10              0
  A            3      0        0            6          34             37
  A            0      0        0            0           5              0
  D            0      0        0            0           3              0
  E            0      0        0            0          1000            0
```

In the end, I have 1900 rows 390 rows( 376( 188 machine error counts + 188 machine error duration) + 14 numerical features) and due to machine errors it is a sparse dataset, lots of 0.

There a none outliers, none nan values, I normalized and tried several classification algorithms( SVM, Logistic Regression, MLPC, XGBoost, etc.)

I also tried PCA but didn't work well, for 165 components explained_variance_ratio is around 0.95

But accuracy metrics are very low, for logistic regression accuracy score is 0.55 and MCC score around 0.1, recall, f1, precision also very low.

Are there some steps that I miss? What would you suggest for multiclass classification for sparse dataset?

Thanks in advance

Comment: first question I always would ask myself, does it really has to be predictable?

Comment: you are right, I occasionaly ask same question in every project but in this case, user selects error type after checking machine error types. so there must be some pattern between them in my opinion.